# jsp scopes of PagesContext

Tags: jsp

Which values can the third attribute of

`javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.setAttribute(String name, Object value, int scope)` can take?

From what I know, this attribute is an enumeration and the possible values i know of are  `PageContext.APPLICATION_SCOPE`,
`PageContext.SESSION_SCOPE`, `PageContext.RESPONSE_SCOPE` and `PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE`. Is this the full set of values?

This is rather a Q of how to "read"

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20int%29

and

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html

-- they aren't too specific if i'm not missing anything.

//=================================

EDIT: Extending the Q:

Is there a way to set the attributes of all of `application`, `session` and `pageContext` all at once from within a JSP.
-- implicitly by the use of a method (of *pageContext* maybe) or as the side-effect of a method 
(of *context* maybe-- from within a servlet as well this time) that does something else?

From what i know, each of these 4 scopes (`request`, `context`, `session`, `pageContext`) can have entirely different attribute sets&values, 
and if i want to pass an attribute to the `context` and the `session`, i have to call their `setAttribute()` each.

//=====================

EDIT: the eclipse editor is telling certain things. this may be an early Q.

Comment: i'll put together a java Q for you panther, promise. :)

Answer (score 0):

This parameter is not an enumeration, but a a plain `int`. PageContext.APPLICATION_SCOPE and so on are constants (public static final int) variables inside PageContext. The full set of values can be found in these links:

- J2EE 1.4: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html
- Java EE 5: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html
- Java EE 6: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html
- Java EE 7: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html

I don't see a reason to set the same value in different scopes. If you need a global value (to the entire application) you will use application scope don't you? If you set the same thing in different scopes, you will need to reset the same value lots of times in more restrictive scopes like session, request and page.

By the way, it is not PageContext.**RESPONSE_SCOPE**, but PageContext.**REQUEST_SCOPE**.

Comment: handling them all at one "hand" is the reason i'm looking for one-method-for-all.

Answer (score 0):

As David has said above, if you need to access a value, you should set it to the broadest scope, rather than trying to reset it again — if you have set an attribute at the application scope, you have access to it everywhere & don't need to set it on the request. That would be redundant.

If you don't know which scope a variable is set on, you can use the [`findAttribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) method on  the context, which will start at page scope & move upwards through request, session & application scopes until it finds the attribute.